# Displaying music beams using the unicode standard

Tags: unicode, fonts

The Unicode Standard version 6.3 [specifies character codes for music](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf) in the range 1D00-1DFF. Two of these are 1D173 (Begin Beam) and 1D174 (End Beam).

Is the purpose of these character codes for specifying the [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Computer_typesetting) start and end points of a [beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_%28music%29) in the resulting output? If so, what's required to achieve the desired output?

Below is an example of beamed notes created using musescore:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the purpose of these characters (which have been in Unicode since version 3.1) explicitly says, in [Ch. 15](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch15.pdf) (p. 537): “Extensive ligature-like beams are used frequently in musical notation between groups of notes having short values. The practice is widespread and very predictable, so it is therefore amenable to algorithmic handling. The format characters U+1D173 musical symbol begin beam and U+1D174 musical symbol end beam can be used to indicate the extents of beam groupings.”.

What you need is rendering software that implements this *and* a font that contains suitable ligature characters. You may also need commands or markup or style sheet that requests for the use of ligatures. In practice, you probably won’t find these, except perhaps in specialized music software.

Comment: By rendering software do you mean something like harfbuzz?

Comment: As of 2019, the Pango rendering engine doesn't appear to render beams. Nor does Chrome's renderer. I haven't found anything that correctly handles beams, even tools that handle joining up glyphs correctly in Arabic writing, etc. Like `الأبجدية العربية` where the `لعر` is joined up not separate `ل ع ر` glyphs. But if I write notes (with spacers) like `'\u2000\u2000♭\u2000\u2000\u2000\u2001\ue8e0\u2001\ue8e0\u2001\u2001\ue8e1\ue8e1\u2000'` (`  ♭        `) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Same if I omit the space glyphs. BTW here's the HTML entity representation (with spaces): `&#x0001d11e;&#x0001d15f;&#x2000;&#x0001d15f;&#x2000;&#x266d;&#x2000;&#x0001d162;&#x2000;&#x0001d13f;&#x2000;&#x0001d161;&#x2001;&#x0000e8e0;&#x0001d15f;&#x2001;&#x0000e8e0;&#x0001d15f;&#x2001;&#x0001d15f;&#x2001;&#x0000e8e1;&#x0000e8e1;&#x2000;` (the first comment's representation is python3)`

Answer (score 1):

I am investigating the same question and have found some partial answers.

There's an example in the book "Unicode Demystified: A Practical Programmer's Guide to the Encoding Standard", shown in the Google Books preview here:

http://books.google.com/books?id=wn5sXG8bEAcC&pg=PA492&lpg=PA492&dq=unicode+begin+beam&source=bl&ots=J16zpZTdUz&sig=FWz9UYUHc3snoUzD7dJuGnPN98Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pauYU63lKsKKyATBs4KwAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=unicode%20begin%20beam&f=false

It says

"The Musical Symbols block includes several invisible formatting characters that, in combination with the musical symbols, signal the beginnings and ends of beamed groups of notes, slurs, ties, and phrase marks.  For example, the sequence

U+1D173 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN BEAM

U+1D160 MUSICAL SYMBOL EIGHTH NOTE

U+1D161 MUSICAL SYMBOL SIXTEENTH NOTE

U+1D175 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN TIE

U+1D161 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN SIXTEENTH NOTE

U+1D174 MUSICAL SYMBOL END BEAM

U+1D173 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN BEAM

U+1D161 MUSICAL SYMBOL SIXTEENTH NOTE

U+1D176 MUSICAL SYMBOL END TIE

U+1D161 MUSICAL SYMBOL SIXTEENTH NOTE

U+1D160 MUSICAL SYMBOL EIGHTH NOTE

U+1D174 MUSICAL SYMBOL END BEAM

would be rendered like this by a sufficiently sophisticated rendering engine: [picture shown]"

Now the question is, what is a "sufficiently sophisticated rendering engine"?  I have tried TextEdit on Mac OS X Mavericks and InDesign.  I installed the Bravura and Bravura Text fonts available from SMuFL (http://www.smufl.org/fonts/).  I, so far, have not been able to create the note beams successfully.